# threejs wireframe with the object materials

Tags: javascript, three.js

i want to get the wireframe of an object that is loaded from `OBJMTLLoder` ,so here i have the code as like below

```
var loader = new THREE.OBJMTLLoader();
                loader.load( 'obj/male02/male02.obj', 'obj/male02/male02_dds.mtl', function ( object ) {

                    object.traverse( function ( child ) {

                    if ( child instanceof THREE.Mesh )
                    {
                    child.geometry.computeFaceNormals();
                    var  geometry = child.geometry;
                    console.log(geometry);
                    geometry.dynamic = true;
                    material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial();
                    mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
                    scene.add(mesh);

                    var useWireFrame = true;
                        if (useWireFrame) {
                            mesh.traverse(function (child) {
                                if (child instanceof THREE.Mesh) child.material.wireframe = true;
                            });
                        }

                    }

                    object.position.y = - 80;
                    scene.add( object );

                    });

                } );
```

this is working well, and i can see the wireframe on my object, unfortunately here my object material is changed into `MeshLambertMaterial`. but i want to get the wireframe of the object with the default material of the object loaded, i can use variety of Material as in the threejs document, but none of them give me a result with the default object material

Answer (score 4):

i got fixed it by add child.material for material , so here is the answer

```
loader.load( 'obj/male02/male02.obj', 'obj/male02/male02_dds.mtl', function ( object ) {

                    object.traverse( function ( child ) {

                    if ( child instanceof THREE.Mesh )
                    {
                    //child.geometry.computeFaceNormals();
                    var  geometry = child.geometry;
                    //console.log(geometry);
                    //geometry.dynamic = true;
                    material = child.material;
                     mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
                        scene.add(mesh);

                    var useWireFrame = true;
                        if (useWireFrame) {
                            mesh.traverse(function (child) {
                                if (child instanceof THREE.Mesh) 
                                {
                                child.material.wireframe = true;
                                child.material.color = new THREE.Color( 0x6893DE  );
                                }
                            });
                        }

                    }

                    object.position.y = - 80;
                    //scene.add( object );

                    });
```

here i added `material = child.material;` as like `geometry = child.geometry;` and it worked fine